# How are isogeny graphs made and how are they helpful to crypto?

Tags: elliptic-curves, post-quantum-cryptography, isogeny

I don't understand how the shapes of isogeny graphs are determined. While Alice and Bob do walk on it and don't backtrack, are they actually relevant to crypto?

Also, I was told that supersingular isogeny graphs are expander graphs. Similarly, how is the shape of an expander graph determined

Comment: I highly recommend https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/593 for an overview of isogeny graphs in cryptography.

Comment: @djao thank you so much for this paper! It ascends to slightly daunting depths very soon, but is immensely helpful. Is there a visual demonstration of the encryption process of SIDH in regards to an isogeny graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let an elliptic curve $E(F_p)$ have the Frobenius discriminant $D_\pi$, and $\left(\frac{D_\pi}{l}\right)$ be a Kronecker symbol for some $l$-degree isogeny. If $\left(\frac{D_\pi}{l}\right)=-1$, then there are no
$l$-degree isogenies; if $\left(\frac{D_\pi}{l}\right)=1$, then two
$l$-degree isogenies exist; if $\left(\frac{D_\pi}{l}\right)=0$, then $1$ or $l+1$ $l$-degree isogenies exist.

> Therefore, if $\left(\frac{D_\pi}{l}\right)=1$. then $l$-degree isogenies of elliptic curves form branchless cycles, and changing
>   direction in a cycle means switching to dual isogenies.

This is a Theorem2 of "PUBLIC-KEY CRYPTOSYSTEM BASED ON ISOGENIES", by Alexander Rostovtsev and Anton Stolbunov.
With this theorem, you can determine the shape of isogeny graphs.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like constructing every graph will be a tedious task (is there any method of automation?)

Comment: @edlothia, It is easy to create a $2n$-regular graph, by choosing the $n$ $l_i$ that $\left(\frac{D_\pi}{l_i}\right)=1$.